Publishing a NET6 Linux-x64 Self-Contained app
I'm trying to publish a Console App with runtime target Linux-x64 on Visual Studio 2022.
The property group Self Contained is set True.
When I publish the application and try to run it on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, it works properly with "./" to execute the program in the terminal.
When I try to run the application double-clicking on the executable file nothing happens.
The executable file has the following properties set.


I would like to open the application double click on the executable file in files explorer.

If only there was a way to search for an answer.

The following may be of interest: https://askubuntu.com/questions/138908/how-to-execute-a-script-just-by-double-clicking-like-exe-files-in-windows

I think the file explorer may be running with a different user or you are getting an exception when running from the explorer.  It should work.  I would check the log files in Ubuntu which is in the /var/log folder.
